# Unicorn April Fools Bug

Tags: bug, unicoins, april-fools

Was it intentional (or just a bug) that in the Unicorn April Fools Joke that when you do the multiply your rep by an amount that it would only be updated in certain places?

On the top of the page you see your (temporarily) "updated" rep and near the bottom you see your original rep again!

Comment: I don't think that's a bug, it's just a way to tell you it's a joke.

Comment: @zdd Unicorns? A *joke*?! **HERESY!**

Comment: @zdd true, but if it was updated everywhere, that the people at SE might be able to convince more people that this **might** be legit (just might...)

Comment: If that was intended, it was not funny at all. It was offending.

Comment: The Unicoins were annoying. Trust me.

Comment: @encadyma Did you eat them?!

Comment: @BlueIce Uh..... no....

Comment: @BlueIce I will eat [those unicorns](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEN5T.jpg)! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicorns are always perfect and always intentional.

Therefore, this is not a bug. Obviously, the unicorns tried hard to make the rep multiplier just the way it is, for reasons only known to them.